# DeleteOnReboot.bat in temp folder

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, anti-virus, temporary-files

I have just taken a glance in my `%temp%` folder, and have found a file called `DeleteOnReboot.bat`. I would not expect to see this sort of thing there, and on inspection with notepad, I can see it contains instructions to force delete a load of registry keys.

Sounds worrying, but on closer inspection, some of the keys I recognise as spam/malware, so I'm wondering whether this file is actually benign - possibly created by my anti-virus.

So my questions are:

- Where did it come from; it has a creation date of a few days ago and I recently temporarily installed *Malwarebytes*, I also have *Norton*. Is this known behaviour for one of them?
- Why is it still in the temp folder - shouldn't this have been cleaned up? The name/ contents imply a one-off program that runs when I turn my computer on (which has probably happened in the last few days since the file got created)
- Should I just run it and/or delete it? It looks like it's just wiping out adware like `sizlsearch` and `Wajam` which I'm guessing is good, but I haven't heard of some of the others like `OCComSDK.ComSDK.1`

The file's not too long so I'll post the contents

```
@echo off
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\LXImageTool.ZIPTool" /f
@echo off
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\LXImageTool.ZIPTool.1" /f
@echo off
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\OCComSDK.ComSDK" /f
@echo off
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\OCComSDK.ComSDK.1" /f
@echo off
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\InternetRegistry\REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-3299057831-706162602-1696328398-1001\Software\mysearchdial" /f
@echo off
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\InternetRegistry\REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-3299057831-706162602-1696328398-1001\Software\sizlsearch" /f
@echo off
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\InternetRegistry\REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-3299057831-706162602-1696328398-1001\Software\Wajam" /f
@echo off
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{AFBCB7E0-F91A-4951-9F31-58FEE57A25C4}" /f
@echo off
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{AFBCB7E0-F91A-4951-9F31-58FEE57A25C4}" /f
@echo off
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.com%2fconduit%2f" /f
```

Comment: Just because you have AV and antimalware does not mean you are 100% secure so you have to use good judgement and common sense as well when it comes to... allowing others to have elevated permissions to the machine while you're not there, browsing the Internet and clicking on various things, etc. and you also need to ensure the security software has its definitions updated and then perform regular full systems scans. What has been recently installed (check Programs and Features), when was the last full AV or AM scan with updated definitions run, who else uses this machine?

Comment: @McDonald's Oh, I'm not hugely worried I've got some virus, I was just listing what AV I have installed as I guessed these might be the source of the file, based on the file's apparent purpose. As it stands, the file was created on the date that I installed and ran Malwarebytes full system scan (in response to a faulty chrome extension that went bad on the same day). I'm guessing that was with the latest definitions. The last Norton full scan w/ updates was maybe a month ago. The only stuff installed in the last couple of months has been that AV and Visual Studio 2017. I'm the only user

Comment: I'd say go ahead and reboot and see what happens and then run the AV and AM software again full scans. These appear to be related to removing the registry values so perhaps AntiMalwareBytes created this to help remove orphaned records and such at the next reboot.